How can I intercept and react to a column header click in a blueprintjs Table2?
I need to react to the click on the column header of a blueprintjs Table2 and ignore the default action of selecting the whole column. However, clicking on the ColumnHeaderCell seems to be hard-coded to trigger column selection.
Ultimately, I was able to react to the selection itself in the Table2.onSelection handler and figure out which column was clicked, but this feels like a hack.
Is there better/proper way to write a custom onClick handler for the ColumnHeaderCell of a Table2?

This is what I've tried:
<ColumnHeaderCell
  nameRenderer={() => <EditableName name={colName} />}
/>

The above renders an EditableName component, which indeed reacts to the click as expected, allowing the user to edit it.
I tried to replace it with a simple div:
const columnHeaderCellRendererFor = (colName: string) => (
  <ColumnHeaderCell
    nameRenderer={() => (<div onClickCapture={e => e.stopPropagation()} onClick={() => {throw "foobar"}}>{colName}</div>)}
  />
);

but nothing happens on click. Instead, the standard column selection behavior of Table2 is triggered.
This is the hack approach I mentioned:
const handleSelection = (regions: Region[]) => {
  // handle row-selection...
  ... else if (regions.length === 1
               && regions[0].cols
               && regions[0].cols[0] === regions[0].cols[1]
) {  // we have a single column click
  const col = regions[0].cols[0];
  // handle column click at index col
}

